# Why am I getting a memory leak?

Tags: go

I have the following: http://play.golang.org/p/1aaive8KQx

When I print the runtime.NumGoroutine() I get 3. Shouldn't I be getting just 1? Why?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        ch := make(chan int, 10)
        timeout := time.Tick(1 * time.Second)
        for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
            go func(i int) {
                time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
                ch <- i
            }(i)
        }

        for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
            select {
            case j := <-ch:
                log.Println(j)
            case <-timeout:
                log.Println("timeout")

            }

        }

        log.Println("Processes", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    }
}
```

Comment: There's always more than 1 goroutine running as part of the runtime. Print the number of goroutines before and after.

Comment: @JimB If I takeout the timeout then I get just 1 running before and after http://play.golang.org/p/5JwJ-2GImJ

Comment: sorry, didn't read closely enough. You're just racing to print the result with the last goroutines finishing. Make your timeout slightly longer, like 1200ms, and you'll only miss 1 result and the rest will be done before you call NumGoroutines.

Comment: (BTW, it is unrelated to this -- there are more goroutines, but they are no longer counted by NumGoroutines. If you panic with GOTRACEBACK=system, you'll see a few more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a weird race condition. Basically what happens is when you call `Println` some goroutines are still running but will terminate shortly. Put a sleep before `Println` and you will get `1 Processes`. If you read the log you will see 2 timeouts - it means you skipped 2 channel reads in the loop. Somehow it gives your main goroutine time to read 8 values from the channel and call `Println` before 2 goroutines are terminated. It's a race condition so it's hard to describe exactly what's going on. Apart from your code the scheduler and channels implementation also play major here.